# Javascript syntax issue with rock paper scissors logic

Tags: javascript

Hey all I am on codeacademy and I am trying to figure out what is wrong with the structure of my function. I thought it was fine but it's not working. Can anyone tell me why?

```
var compare = function (choice1,choice2){
if("choice1 = choice2"){
    return ("The result is a tie!");
}
};
compare(1,1);

if ("choice1 = rock"){
    if ("choice2 = scissors"){
        return ("rock wins");
    } else {
        return ("paper wins");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check some manuals, Google, the internet. I'd start here http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/javascript-basics

Comment: You mix up variables with strings

Comment: I guess you're a beginner? check on operators. == or === for equal to. keep coding!

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statements should not be in quotes.  By putting them in quotes, you are evaluating the truthfulness of a non-empty string, which will always be `true` by Javascript standards.

Furthermore, the comparisons in your `if` statements use a single `=` sign.  Logical comparisons should use either two `=` signs (checks for equality after type conversion) or three `=` signs (which fails if the types are different).

Comment: I updated the code and it's telling me choice1 was not defined?

Comment: *"you are evaluating whether or not the value of some text is true, which will always be false by Javascript standard"* uh? Any non-empty string evaluates to true!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll bite...

Your conditional statements are in quotes.

EDIT: Also need to use `==` (or `===`) for comparison

Comment: Thanks for biting. I always add quotes when I get nervous that something isnt working!

Answer (score 0):

equal to is == not =

```
var compare = function (choice1,choice2){
  if(choice1 == choice2){
    return ("The result is a tie!");
  }
};
compare(1,1);

if (choice1 == "rock"){
   if (choice2 == "scissors"){
    return ("rock wins");
    } else {
       return ("paper wins");
  }
}
```

And your quotes misplaced